# how to get the certificate from gtalk XMPP server?

Tags: java, certificate, xmpp, ssl-certificate

I'm writing an application to obtain the certificate from XMPP Server. But after that, I cannot figure out the way to ask for it. Here is my Java code:

```
            Socket connection =new Socket("talk.google.com", 5222);
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input,"UTF-8"));
        BufferedWriter to_server = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8")
                );
        String responseLine="";
        to_server.write(initiate_conn);
        to_server.flush();
        int in;
        while(!(responseLine.contains("</stream:features>")))
        {
            responseLine += (char)d.read();   
        }
        System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
        to_server.write(start_tls);
        to_server.flush();
        responseLine="";
        while(!(responseLine.contains("<proceed xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls\"/>")))
            responseLine += (char)d.read();  
        System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
```

and the result I get is as follows:

```
Server: stream:stream from="110.47.18.148" id="2D416C8DE320C481" version="1.0" x
mlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" stream:fea
tures starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls" required  starttls m
echanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"  mechanism X-OAUTH2  mechanis
m mechanism X-GOOGLE-TOKEN mechanism mechanisms stream:features
Server:  proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"
```

Does anyone know how to obtain the certificate after these? Thank you so much!